# Сортировать время и дату

Tags: c#, linq, blazor

```
... .OrderByDescending(day => day.DEN).ThenBy(hours => hours.CAS);
```

`json` беру из бд `sql`, чтоб показать в приложении. в базе данных два поля сохранены по отдельности и также в таблице показываю расписание с двумя полями, время и дата, необходимо сортировать расписание, чтоб на сегодня показывал все с утра и до вечера, а когда таблица показывает расписание вчерашнего дня (все еще в той же таблице), чтоб было с вечера и к утру, *СОРТИРОВКА ПО ВОЗРАСТАНИЮ* тоесть
при таком запросе у меня выходит на сегодняшний день все как и ожидаю, то есть 9, 10, 11 итд, а на второй день пишет тоже самое в графе день вчера-ок, а графа часа как на сегодня 9,10,11..., как можно вчерашний и более ранние дни сделать наоборот, тоесть 18.00, 17.00, 16.00 то есть, чтоб было **по возрастанию по двум полям сортировка ?**

вот что я вижу

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

```
... .OrderByDescending(day => day.DEN).ThenByDescending(hours => hours.CAS);
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

```
... .OrderBy(day => day.DEN).ThenByDescending(hours => hours.CAS);
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

а надо на сегодня как есть с утра, а вчера с вечера

`blazor web assembly C#`

Comment: ThenByDescending?

Comment: спасибо большое, а может вы в ответе оформите, так я смогу принять ваш ответ, так сразу будет бросаться в глаза для тех кто ищет как я, а сам не додумался

Comment: аннНет, я поторопилась

Comment: он показывает и сегодня с последнего то есть с вечера начинает...

Comment: Не понимаю, вы сами говорите про "по возрастанию", а потом "18.00, 17.00, 16.00" - это явно не возрастание, OrderByDescending - по убыванию, что вы и хотите ("18.00, 17.00, 16.00")

Comment: Минимальный возводимый пример для вас: https://pastebin.com/FB7PYPFy, в переменной ```data``` смотрите данные, может вы в интерфейсе запутались?

Comment: Возможно вам нужно OrderBy(..).ThenByDescending(..)

Comment: @OwDafuq я изменила вопрос все три варианта скрин экрана добавила, мне думается, что там наверно надо играть с if-ами, типа если день вчера толяляля итп только моя логика пока не отвечает

Comment: @OwDafuq на сегодня 9,10,11 а потом идет вчера и там уже 18,17,16

Comment: Сегодняшний день сортировать отдельно от вчерашних? Тогда да, это 2 разных списка по идее должно быть

Comment: если пользователь ```stackOverflow``` вобьет в поиск ```сортировать```  он увидит, тут примеры различные и полезные для него, в моем же случае немного нестандартно и писать в заголовке вопроса сортировать на сегодня, но отсортировывать на завтра===> как то непонятно, поэтому вопрос немного общий у меня, а тут кто уже например сталкивался именно с такой сортировкой зайдет и ответит @OwDafuq благодарю за ваше участие

Comment: Если вопрос решился, то оформите ответ, чтобы пользователям было проще его найти :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Первое, что на ум приходит - разделить список на два сегмента: текущий день и все остальное.

```
int day = dateList.Select(day => day.DEN).Max();
IEnumerable<...> first = dateList.Where(day => day.DEN.Equals(day));
IEnumerable<...> other = dateList.Where(day => !day.DEN.Equals(day));
```

Потом сортировать их по отдельности как нужно и обратно объединить:

```
first = first.OrderByDescending(hours => hours.CAS);
other = other.OrderByDescending(day => day.DEN).ThenBy(hours => hours.CAS);
IEnumerable<...> sorted = first.Concat(other);
```

---

Пример работы (Консоль .NET 6):

```
List<dateClass> dateList = new List<dateClass>()
{
  new dateClass(){ DAY = 03, HOUR = 18 },
  new dateClass(){ DAY = 04, HOUR = 18 },
  new dateClass(){ DAY = 04, HOUR = 16 },
  new dateClass(){ DAY = 03, HOUR = 17 },
  new dateClass(){ DAY = 03, HOUR = 16 },
  new dateClass(){ DAY = 04, HOUR = 17 }
};

int day = dateList.Select(x => x.DAY).Max();
IEnumerable<dateClass> first = dateList.Where(x => x.DAY.Equals(day));
IEnumerable<dateClass> other = dateList.Where(x => !x.DAY.Equals(day));
first = first.OrderByDescending(x => x.HOUR);
other = other.OrderByDescending(x => x.DAY).ThenBy(x => x.HOUR);
IEnumerable<dateClass> sorted = first.Concat(other);
Console.WriteLine(string.Join(Environment.NewLine, sorted.Select(x => x.DAY.ToString() + ": " + x.HOUR.ToString())));

class dateClass
{
  public int DAY { get; set; }
  public int HOUR { get; set; }
}
```

Выводит:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

---

Еще как вариант добавить столбцы нумерации из базы SQL. Например разные сортировки `ROW_NUMBER()` от `DENSE_RANK()` по дате:

```
SELECT
  [t],
  CASE
    WHEN [t] = 1
    THEN ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY [b] ORDER BY [a] DESC)
    ELSE ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY [b] ORDER BY [a])
  END AS [N],
  [b],
  [a]
FROM
  (
    SELECT
      DENSE_RANK() OVER (ORDER BY [b] DESC) AS [t],
      [b],
      [a]
    FROM
      (
        SELECT
          CONVERT([date], [a]) AS [b],
          [a]
        FROM
          (
            SELECT CONVERT([datetime], '2023-04-05 18:25:43', 120) AS [a]
            UNION ALL
            SELECT CONVERT([datetime], '2023-04-07 18:04:43', 120)
            UNION ALL
            SELECT CONVERT([datetime], '2023-04-07 18:25:00', 120)
            UNION ALL
            SELECT CONVERT([datetime], '2023-04-07 17:14:12', 120)
            UNION ALL
            SELECT CONVERT([datetime], '2023-04-06 18:11:11', 120)
            UNION ALL
            SELECT CONVERT([datetime], '2023-04-06 16:01:35', 120)
            UNION ALL
            SELECT CONVERT([datetime], '2023-04-06 17:45:52', 120)
          ) t
      ) t2
  ) t3
ORDER BY
  [t],
  [N]
```

| t | N | b | a |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 | 2023-04-07 | 2023-04-07 18:25:00.000 |
| 1 | 2 | 2023-04-07 | 2023-04-07 18:04:43.000 |
| 1 | 3 | 2023-04-07 | 2023-04-07 17:14:12.000 |
| 2 | 1 | 2023-04-06 | 2023-04-06 16:01:35.000 |
| 2 | 2 | 2023-04-06 | 2023-04-06 17:45:52.000 |
| 2 | 3 | 2023-04-06 | 2023-04-06 18:11:11.000 |
| 3 | 1 | 2023-04-05 | 2023-04-05 18:25:43.000 |